# Webstorm uses wrong git user

Tags: git, webstorm

I have right user.name and user.email in git config --global and --local. 
But when i try to push ro github, it tries to push with another user.
As well, i have right data in VCS github settings, tested connection.

See no any other options or anything etc. for this.

Comment: What does "push with a different user" mean? You push with an SSH key, but commit with a user/email. Is the commit made with the wrong user? What makes you say it uses the wrong user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account used for pushing has nothing to do with `user.name` and `user.email` git settings.

It will be the GitHub account if you are using an https url with your GitHub login, or your GitHub account if you are using ssh, and have registered your public key to that account.

When you are [pushing a git repo with Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/pushing-changes-to-the-upstream-git-push.html), you must check what url is registered to the remote name you are pushing to (like, for instance, `origin`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yep, have started to configure SSH keys.

Comment: Actually another thing user need to do is to use right data in author field during commit creation, because if old username + email is here 
Old User <olduser@gmail.com>

You can change your ssh keys, git config and etc. forever. Just check what is in Author field while create your commits and if wrong user is there, just type New User <newuser@gmail.com>

Comment: _It will be the GitHub account if you are using an https url with your GitHub login_ what is _the GitHub account_? How is it different from _your GitHub account_?  And of course the correct url is registered to the remote name so what then?

Comment: "How is it different from your GitHub account?" Because with an ssh url, you are using the `git` account: `git@github.com`. Your account only comes into play if `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is registered to your GitHub account.